# Unable to Render Bundle (404) - React with Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs, webpack

I've been stuck for a while in this part to render a simple, basic HTML page with a react container. What happens is that the system is unable to find the bundle, popping out the following error in the browser - element inspection:
`main-e81ebca393352343ecd4.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)`

While popping the following error in the "python manage.py runserver" terminal window:

```
[29/Aug/2017 16:40:57] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 269
[29/Aug/2017 16:40:57] "GET /static/bundles/main-e81ebca393352343ecd4.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1721
```

Now I've been through multiple times my settings.py file and my webpackconfig.js file, however, I havent been able to find where is my mistake so far.

**webpack.config.js:**

```
//require our dependencies
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')

module.exports = {
    //the base directory (absolute path) for resolving the entry option
    context: __dirname,
    //the entry point we created earlier. Note that './' means 
    //your current directory. You don't have to specify the extension  now,
    //because you will specify extensions later in the `resolve` section
    entry: './assets/js/index', 

    output: {
        //where you want your compiled bundle to be stored
        path: path.resolve('./assets/bundles/'), 
        //naming convention webpack should use for your files
        filename: '[name]-[hash].js', 
    },

    plugins: [
        //tells webpack where to store data about your bundles.
        new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}), 
        //makes jQuery available in every module
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ 
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery' 
        })
    ],

    module: {
        loaders: [
            //a regexp that tells webpack use the following loaders on all 
            //.js and .jsx files
            {test: /\.jsx?$/, 
                //we definitely don't want babel to transpile all the files in 
                //node_modules. That would take a long time.
                exclude: /node_modules/, 
                //use the babel loader 
                loader: 'babel-loader', 
                query: {
                    //specify that we will be dealing with React code
                    presets: ['react'] 
                }
            }
        ]
    },

    resolve: {
        //tells webpack where to look for modules
        modules: ["node_modules"],
        //extensions that should be used to resolve modules
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'] 
    }   
}
```

**settings.py:** (Cut)

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIR = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),
)

WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
    'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'bundles/',
    'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webpack-stats.json'),
    }
}
```

**url.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
]
```

**index.html**

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello Django+React!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    </div>
    {% render_bundle 'main' %}
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
var React = require('react')
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom')

var Hello = React.createClass ({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <h1>
             Hello, React! How do you do?
            </h1>
        )
    }
})

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('container'))
```

[Folder Path/Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjE2J.png)

Now This is what I've tried so far:

- Change the *STATIC_URL = '/static/'*: The path also changes in the error; however its no big deal as it still with the same error (Even if I use "/assets/" as my static directory.
- Browse through my urls.py and webpack file over and over again, no success also.

It seems to me that I'm been unable to proper define the path for the index.js file for instance, as webpack-loader is been able to generate the bundle without any concerns.

Thanks in advance for your attention.

Comment: your looking into `/static/bundles` instead of `assets/bundles/`? your output is set as: `path: path.resolve('./assets/bundles/')`

Comment: Helllo Sag1v, thank you for your answer.

Actually the Browser GET is looking into /static/bundles for some reason, even though I've set is for them to be looking at /assets/bundles (where there is an existing bundle). No idea what to do.

Comment: Have you read this https://stackoverflow.com/q/35920691/3148807

Comment: Yes! I've reviewed those steps and tried on my application as well. Unfortunately, there is no success. 

I've been wondering what is going on with this particular application, because I could test several other examples, but can see the thing with this one. 

Thank you again, Sag1v.